# API REST - Different parameters followed by ? and &

Tags: java, json, rest, api

I'm doing an API in my web system because of a task in university. The problem is that I'm not able to do a specific part and I think that it's very easy.

The statement says:

*GET /rest/api/v1/tfg?State = ${state}

List of all TFGs in the indicated state. You can indicate different states at the same time. To do this, you must repeat the state parameter multiple times (such as: "?State=state1&State=state2&State=state3"), and the web service will return all those who are in any of these states.*

I have a DB with projects (TFGs) and I know how to get this data, but the problems are that I don't know what to do to detect ? in URL, and how can I do to read different parameters depending on the quantity. It's possible to have one state or N states. How can I do it?

The current code is this:

```
@Path("/rest/api/v1/tfg")
public class TfgREST {
@GET
@Path("")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response findAll() throws ServletException, IOException {
    TfgDao dao = new TfgDao();
    LinkedList<Projecte> llista = dao.findAll(true); //TRUE because of API

    JsonArrayBuilder array = Json.createArrayBuilder();

    for(Projecte p : llista){
       array.add(p.getTitol());
    }

    return Response.ok(array.build()).build();    
}

@GET
@Path("/?state={state}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response findByState(@PathParam("state") String state) throws ServletException, IOException {
    TfgDao dao = new TfgDao();
    LinkedList<String> llista = dao.findByState(state);

    //JsonObjectBuilder jo = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    JsonArrayBuilder array = Json.createArrayBuilder();

    for(String p : llista){
        array.add(p);
    }
    return Response.ok(array.build()).build();    
}
```

If I call http://...../rest/api/v1/tfg?State=XXXX, web invokes the first one (findAll) but, if I use /rest/api/v1/tfg/State=XXX it works...

Thanks for all! I'm waiting for your answers.

Miquel

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html

Comment: I have used QueryParam but now I want to have two types. If I put /rest/api/v1/tfg it prints all projects but if I put /rest/api/v1/tfg?state=... it should print projects with this states... How can I do it? I tried with an if(state == null) and it doesn't work

Comment: I've added the solution in answers. I'll mark as accepted in two days, when system let me do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, now it's working. I publish the solution in order to contribute with you and try to solve this problem in a future for other people.

I mixed both methods in one implemeting an if.

The code is the following:

```
@Path("/rest/api/v1/tfg")
public class TfgREST {

@GET
@Path("")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response findAll(@QueryParam("state") List<String> state) throws ServletException, IOException {
    TfgDao dao = new TfgDao();
    JsonArrayBuilder array = Json.createArrayBuilder();

    if(state.isEmpty()){
        LinkedList<Projecte> llista = dao.findAll(true); //TRUE because of API

        for(Projecte p : llista){
           array.add(p.getTitol());
        }
    }
    else{
        LinkedList<String> projs;
        for (String s : state){
            projs = dao.findByState(s);
            for (String x : projs){
                array.add(x);
            }
        }
    }

    return Response.ok(array.build()).build();    
}
}
```

Thanks for your contributions, I finally got it, and it has been very easy!

Answer (score 0):

Because REST API follows resource.

if "state" is a object, you can use */rest/api/v1/tfg/State=XXX*
**BUT** if "state" is only a property of *tfg*, you use /rest/api/v1/tfg?State=XXX

Comment: Yes, but if I want to do the following thing: If I put /rest/api/v1/tfg it prints all projects but if I put /rest/api/v1/tfg?state=... it should print projects with this states... How can I do it? I tried with an if(state == null) and it doesn't work

I can't do two methods because they have collisions with Path

Comment: @Path("/?state={state}"), I think that: @Path("?state={state}")

Comment: But if I was you, I would only have a method and use if else with a few parameters.